# Bounty badge with unreadable text on Reputation page

Tags: bug, design

The badge showing the amount earned for any given bounty has a trouble with the text color... The location is;

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/{userId}?tab=reputation
```

[image]

It seems that this is due to the class `rep-up` on the `<span>` element holding the value.

```
<span class="rep-up bounty-indicator-tab">+200</span>
```

Without the `rep-up` class, the coloring is normal again...

[image]

---

Having only `rep-up` class makes the text green with no background, [image]
and this does not work well with `bounty-indicator-tab` class, it seems. Together the text still stays green with blue badge, which makes it really hard and awkward to see the value.